# How to count single field twice in one query based on different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count the same field twice, distinct based on different conditions from another subquery. The pseudo code would be something like this:

```
select countd(svc_ord_nbr) <if start_dt = end_dt> as fixed, 
       countd(svc_ord_nbr) <else> as unfixed
       from [subquery]
```

The subquery is basically getting the min and max of the activity date based on the same svc_ord_nbr

```
select svc_ord_nbr, date_part('day', min(e.START_DTM)) as start_dt,
    date_part('day', max(e.START_DTM)) as end_dt
    from order o join activity a on o.svc_activity_id = a.activity_id
    group by svc_ord_nbr
```

The answer in [How to count same field twice based on a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481111/how-to-count-same-field-twice-based-on-a-boolean) suggests to do `case when` on the boolean. However, it does not take the distinct value into account. Is there a way to count the same field twice only for distanct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
  count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN start_dt = end_dt THEN svc_ord_nbr END) as fixed, 
  count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN start_dt <> end_dt THEN svc_ord_nbr END )as unfixed
from [subquery];
```

---

Alternatively using windowed functions:

```
select DISTINCT
  count(DISTINCT svc_ord_nbr) FILTER(WHERE start_dt = end_dt) OVER() as fixed, 
  count(DISTINCT svc_ord_nbr) FILTER(WHERE start_dt <> end_dt) OVER() as unfixed
from [subquery];
```

You could add `PARTITION BY` inside  `OVER` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [filter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html) on a aggregate function:

```
select count(distinct svc_ord_nbr) FILTER (WHERE start_dt = end_dt) as fixed, 
       count(distinct svc_ord_nbr) FILTER (WHERE start_dt <> end_dt) as unfixed
from [subquery];
```